# ipsec / OpenSwan VPN limit

Tags: vpn, ipsec, openswan

What is the through put limit of ipsec / OpenSwan?

I am connecting to a Cisco ASA

I am using ipsec version:

Linux Openswan U2.6.37/K3.2.22-35.60.amzn1.x86_64 (netkey)

Answer (score 1):

The IPsec throughput is dependent on the underlying hardware platform (specifically CPU cores).  There is no hard limit baked into the software implementation itself.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on CPU and what kind of cipher is used. [See this link for more info](http://iceta.sk/proceedings/iceta2011_truchly.pdf)